# How to make a sticky post on appear on top within a view

Tags: 7

I've created a view which is organised by date. All works fine, however I'd like to add the sticky functionality to it, where whenever a node is marked as sticky, it'll go to the top of the list regardless of the date. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just sort by sticky and after that sort by date.

As simple as that, it should do the trick for what you want to do.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. :)