# Make a news item "sticky at the top of lists"

Tags: views

I want to sort my news items by sticky to the top and then date so I can highlight certain news items. The same question was asked [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174287/how-to-make-a-sticky-post-on-appear-on-top-within-a-view), the answer was to:

> "Just sort by sticky and after that sort by date."

I did this and it showed correctly in my preview on the news edit page. However when I went to my live news page it did not register the "sticky to the top" setting and still only sorted by date created. Why is my news edit page not making those changes on the live page?

here's a screenshot, maybe I have a setting wrong:
[image]

Comment: Did you try flush the cache?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to do that.. What does that accomplish?

Comment: Your view uses a tag based caching mechanism. It could be that that it has not refreshed the cache, and because of that won't show the changes on the actual page. You can clear the cache on "Administer > Site Configuration > Performance" and hit the "Clear cached data" button

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!